# Rails 4.1 Unable to display reviews form page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to add movie reviews to my movie app. But when anyone can add reviews it does not show on the page

rails console shows the comment and rating

```
=> #<Review id: 3, **movie_rating: 2, comment: "test",** created_at: "2015-02-12 11:20:10", updated_at: "2015-02-12 11:20:10", user_id: 2, movie_id: nil>
```

but does not appear on my show.html.erb page

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <% if @reviews.blank? %>
  <h3>No reviews yet. Be the first to write one!</h3>
  <% else %>
  <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <p><%= review.movie_rating %></p>
  <p><%= review.comment %></p>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(@movie), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', movies_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
```

and have defined this in my movies_controller page under show

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /movies
  # GET /movies.json
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  # GET /movies/1
  # GET /movies/1.json
  def show
    **@reviews = Review.where(movie_id: @movie.id)**
  end

  # GET /movies/new
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  # GET /movies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /movies
  # POST /movies.json
  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.save
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.update(movie_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /movies/1
  # DELETE /movies/1.json
  def destroy
    @movie.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to movies_url, notice: 'Movie was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def movie_params
      params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :description, :movie_length, :director, :rating, :image)
    end
end
```

review_controller.rb

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_movie
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  respond_to :html



  def new
    @review = Review.new
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.movie_id = @movie_id

    @review.save
    respond_with(@movie)
  end

  def update
    @review.update(review_params)
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  private
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    end

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:movie_rating, :comment)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you noticed that **`movie_id`** produced in the **`log`** is **`nil`**?.This is because of this line `@review.movie_id = @movie_id` in your `create` method of your `reviews_controller` is **wrong**.It should be `@review.movie_id = @movie.id`.

```
def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.movie_id = @movie.id #here

    @review.save
    respond_with(@movie)
  end
```

This is the reason for `reviews` being not shown as they have `movie_id` **nil**.